# Service throwing an Unknown Host Exception Android App

Tags: java, android, httpwebrequest

I am trying to check a variable amount of websites in a service that is woken up by an alarm every 15 minutes.  The problem I'm having is when I start the service to check the websites it is giving me an java.net.UnknownHostException for a website I know is good.  Perhpas I don't fully understand the error that is being spit out, but I'm not sure why the code is giving me such a problem.

Here is the stack:

```
06-28 19:30:06.270: WARN/System.err(560): java.net.UnknownHostException: http://www.cnn.com/
06-28 19:30:06.480: WARN/System.err(560):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:513)
06-28 19:30:06.480: WARN/System.err(560):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:280)
06-28 19:30:06.490: WARN/System.err(560):     at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:310)
06-28 19:30:06.520: WARN/System.err(560):     at com.myapp.tracker.Listen.checkWebsite(Listen.java:102)
06-28 19:30:06.520: WARN/System.err(560):     at com.myapp.tracker.Listen.onStartCommand(Listen.java:64)
06-28 19:30:06.520: WARN/System.err(560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3053)
06-28 19:30:06.530: WARN/System.err(560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-28 19:30:06.530: WARN/System.err(560):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2096)
06-28 19:30:06.530: WARN/System.err(560):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-28 19:30:06.530: WARN/System.err(560):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-28 19:30:06.550: WARN/System.err(560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-28 19:30:06.550: WARN/System.err(560):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 19:30:06.550: WARN/System.err(560):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-28 19:30:06.550: WARN/System.err(560):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-28 19:30:06.550: WARN/System.err(560):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-28 19:30:06.550: WARN/System.err(560):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code:

```
public void checkWebsite(Intent intent) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        int [] checkboxes = bundle.getIntArray("checkboxes");
        if( checkboxes[0] == 0){
            String failure = "******FAILURE VALUE = 0";
            Log.d(TRACKER_DEBUGGING, failure);  
        }
        String [] websites = bundle.getStringArray("websites");
        if( websites[0] == null){
            String failure = "******FAILURE VALUE = null";
            Log.d(TRACKER_DEBUGGING, failure);  
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

            if( checkboxes[i] == 1 ){
                request.setURI(new URI(websites[i]));
                Log.d(TRACKER_DEBUGGING, websites[i]);

                // this line right here is throwing the error
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

// more code after this but it never reaches this point or executes any of it
```

I'm super perplexed as to why this is happening.  I guess I'm not really all that familiar with Http requests, but I feel like this should work.

EDIT***********:   I swore that I had added the uses internet permission but I had not actually added it.  Now I know to triple check for that when I run into an UnknownHostException in the future.

Upvotes for all that took the time to answer and thank you for entertaining my idiocy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might be because you do not have Internet access in the manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: The permission is in the manifest.  A previous version was working.

Answer (score 3):

The WiFi or networking layer might be going to sleep: when the service wakes up from the alarm it may need to wait a few seconds until the networking layer comes back up and re-establishes communication before trying the HTTP request.

EDIT: alternatively you may need to use a wake lock to grab access to the wifi and prevent it from going to sleep.

Comment: Only thing I could think of is your `websites[i]` variable is not a proper URL.

Answer (score 2):

If none of the previous answers fixed it, then, are you running this in an emulator? The network layer in the emulator likes to throw these errors every once in a while to confuse/frustrate you. Cheeky, that one. Restart it and everything should be back to normal.

Comment: I have been testing on the emulator so I will test on my droid next.  It would certainly be aggravating if the emulator didn't work but the device did, from a development standpoint not deployment of course.

Comment: testing on my droid is giving me the exact same error in LogCat